# Which architecture for Intel Atom CPU N270: amd64 or i386?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have and old netbook with 1gb of ram and an Atom N270 CPU.  I want to install Ubuntu 14.04.  Which one should I use amd64 or i386?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 32bit only: http://ark.intel.com/products/36331/Intel-Atom-Processor-N270-512K-Cache-1_60-GHz-533-MHz-FSB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel Atom N270 does NOT have 64-bit support, so you have to install 32-bit (i386) version.
You can view that at [Intel Webpage](http://ark.intel.com/products/36331/Intel-Atom-Processor-N270-512K-Cache-1_60-GHz-533-MHz-FSB) where it says:

> Intel® 64:    No

You said your netbook has 1GB of RAM: When you download Ubuntu in the [official Ubuntu webpage](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), they recommend installing the 32-bit version if your computer has less than 2GB of RAM.